# How to use http websocket on Mongoose embedded web server with SSL?

Tags: ssl, mongoose, websocket, ssl-certificate, mongoose-web-server

I'm trying to use Http WebSocket on Mongoose embedded web server with SSL.

And I tried this mongoose example called "simplest_web_server_ssl".
But when I executed the program, it printed out this message below.

"Failed to create listener: Invalid SSL cert"

I think it's because the program doesn't know where the "server.pem" file is.
I put these "server.pem" and "server.key" files from the example folder into a "release" folder where the .exe file is created and runs.

Actually I'm quite new to Mongoose and SSL.

Please anybody could help me?

Thanks, regards.

```
/*
* Copyright (c) 2016 Cesanta Software Limited
* All rights reserved
*/

/*
* This example starts an SSL web server on https://localhost:8443/
*
* Please note that the certificate used is a self-signed one and will not be
* recognised as valid. You should expect an SSL error and will need to
* explicitly allow the browser to proceed.
*/

#include "mongoose.h"

static const char *s_http_port = "8443";
static const char *s_ssl_cert = "server.pem";
static const char *s_ssl_key = "server.key";
static struct mg_serve_http_opts s_http_server_opts;

static void ev_handler(struct mg_connection *nc, int ev, void *p) {
    if (ev == MG_EV_HTTP_REQUEST) {
        mg_serve_http(nc, (struct http_message *) p, s_http_server_opts);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct mg_mgr mgr;
    struct mg_connection *nc;
    struct mg_bind_opts bind_opts;
    const char *err;

    mg_mgr_init(&mgr, NULL);
    memset(&bind_opts, 0, sizeof(bind_opts));
    bind_opts.ssl_cert = s_ssl_cert;
    bind_opts.ssl_key = s_ssl_key;
    bind_opts.error_string = &err;

    printf("Starting SSL server on port %s, cert from %s, key from %s\n",
        s_http_port, bind_opts.ssl_cert, bind_opts.ssl_key);
    nc = mg_bind_opt(&mgr, s_http_port, ev_handler, bind_opts);
    if (nc == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to create listener: %s\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up HTTP server parameters
    mg_set_protocol_http_websocket(nc);
    s_http_server_opts.document_root = ".";  // Serve current directory
    s_http_server_opts.enable_directory_listing = "yes";

    for (;;) {
        mg_mgr_poll(&mgr, 1000);
    }
    mg_mgr_free(&mgr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. You can step into mongoose using gdb or similar tool to find the actual reason for that error message. If you think mongoose isn't finding your files, try using absolute paths. If it finds the file, you might need to regenerate (and/or register) the cert files on your computer.